# Change class only for one element in td

Tags: jquery

I use the following function to add a class 'active' to an element in a table:
The td can contain textareas, inputs, etc. 
The class should only be added to the textarea, input, etc. and not to the entire td. 
Thank you for your tips

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    var table = $('table').on('focusin', 'td', function() {
        $('.table tr td').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.toolbar').show();
    });
});
$(function() {
    var table = $('table').on('focusout', 'td', function() {
        $('.table tr td').removeClass('active');
        $('.toolbar').hide();
```

});
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use descendant traversing using [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find), you will have to make corresponding changes to `removeClass()` also

```
$(function () {
    var table = $('table').on('focusin', 'td', function () {
        $('.table tr td .active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).find(':input').addClass('active');
        $('.toolbar').show();
    });
});
$(function () {
    var table = $('table').on('focusout', 'td', function () {
        $('.table tr td .active').removeClass('active');
        $('.toolbar').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Currently the class is added to all inputs within the td-Elemens. I would like to add the class only to the clicked item. Another problem is when the clicked element is a textarea.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`jQuery.find`](http://api.jQuery.com/find)

```
$(this).find(":input").addClass('active');
```

And for removing

```
$(this).find(".active").removeClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

change your line

```
$(this).addClass('active');
```

to

```
$(this).find(':input')addClass('active');
```

for input fields, and additionally for textarea fields

```
$(this).find(':textarea')addClass('active');
```